# Photoswipe set image caption with html code

Tags: drupal-7, photoswipe

I'm using drupal7 Photoswipe module which uses Photoswipe jQuery plugin to build a view and display a gallery of photos. 
Currently Photoswipe allows only to display image title as image caption.

Also to display other text fields from the same content node, I add content text fields to the view and change their display to add a CSS class (.photo_text).

Then I modified openPhotoSwipe function within photoswipe.jquery.js to get the image parent html node ($image .parents("td:first") ) and select it's children having the (.photo_text) CSS class, to add them as image title.

```
openPhotoSwipe: function(index, galleryElement, options) {
  var pswpElement = $('.pswp')[0];
  var items = [];
  options = options || Drupal.behaviors.photoswipe.photoSwipeOptions;

  var images = galleryElement.find('a.photoswipe');
  images.each(function (index) {
    var $image = $(this);
    var $eleme = $image.parents("td:first");
    var $eleme_class = $eleme.children('.photo_text');
    var $photo_text = "";
    if ( !!$eleme_class){
        for ( var i = 0; i < $eleme_class.length; i++ ){
            $photo_text += $eleme_class[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
        $photo_text = "";
    }
    // end of add 
    size = $image.data('size') ? $image.data('size').split('x') : ['',''];
    items.push(
      {
        src : $image.attr('href'),
        w: size[0],
        h: size[1],
        title : $image.data('overlay-title') + $photo_text
      }
    );
  })
```

I'm now wondering if it exists a simplest way to do the same thing without modifying this module?